# Rails migration not adding id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm on Rails 4.2 and Postgres 9.5

I was using the following migration and it is not adding the id column automatically:

```
class AddCharacteristics < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :characteristics do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

The resulting table as defined in db/schema.rb does not have an id column:

```
create_table "characteristics", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

The id column not being in the schema.rb is a non-issue as pointed out.  However I cannot access the characteristic object from the console:

```
2.3.0 :003 >   Characteristic.last
  Characteristic Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "characteristics".* FROM  "characteristics"  ORDER BY "characteristics"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "characteristics" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "characteristics".* FROM "characteristics"  ORDER BY...
                                     ^
: SELECT  "characteristics".* FROM "characteristics"  ORDER BY "characteristics"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
```

In PSQL console this query works fine:

```
# SELECT  "characteristics".* FROM "characteristics"  ORDER BY "characteristics"."id" DESC LIMIT 1;
 id | name |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | test | 2016-01-29 12:58:24.225279 | 2016-01-29 12:58:24.225279
```

Comment: please check in your Rails console like `Characteristic.column_names` . `id` will not be present in the schema.rb..

Comment: The id column is in the database but the console doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work means ?

Answer (score 4):

Don't worry, id columns are not shown in schema.rb but they exist in the DB.

For example: https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/db/schema.rb

> The edited question about my console not working was because my console was in test, but my database query was in development

If you are using RSpec and want to keep the development and test environments in sync, you might want to add `ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!` in rails_helper.rb.

References:

- https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/upgrade#pending-migration-checks
- https://github.com/everydayrails/rails-4-1-rspec-3-0/blob/master/spec/rails_helper.rb#L16